# State Machine vs Switch Case

Tags: c++, c++11, state-machine, rhapsody

I am using Rational Rhapsody for project development. I am using a state machine for state (screen) transitions, which can be done using a `switch` as well. I want to know what are advantages of state machine in Rational Rhapsody when compared to `switch` statements.

Comment: Last time I used a state machine, it was done with a switch case construct. Your tags are contradicting. You can use either C or C++ but not both at the same time.

Comment: Ya it is either c or c++,I am using c++

Comment: Then please do not add unrelated language tags.

Comment: @Gerhardh what the problem with usage of C and C++ simultaneously? They are perfectly compatible.

Comment: They are different languages with different rules. The fact that some part of syntax and semantics is similar does not make them same language. Lots of them are very **non**-compatible.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev not at all. You can construct a usable subset of both languages to make polyglots with, but that subset is both lame C and awful C++.

Comment: lol guys, you are so religious, that compatibility makes your OS work for example

Comment: @AntonMalyshev you can interoperate C and C++ binaries via `extern "C"`. That is *not* using both simultaneously. In any case, a vague question that does not even settle on a language cannot produce a good result.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371460/state-machines-tutorials or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676709/c-code-for-state-machine

Comment: A state machine can also be implemented with switch. So the question is fully off topic. One is a design question and one is implementation detail. So how can it be compared are argued?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little off-mark :

A state machine is a "concept", while a switch-case is a possible implementation of a state machine.

It's like saying "can we do imperative programmation in C++ ?".
Imperative programmation is the concept (paradigme here), and it's possible to do it in C++.

You can implement state machine by switch-case, array, linked list .... 
It's up to you to know if you really need a state machine and how to implement it.